# Modifying an attribute for each object in a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, attributes, django-queryset

I've been using Django for over a year, but I think I've missed out on some very fundamental thing. I have a rather large queryset (1000+ objects) and I'd like to change a single attribute for each of the objects in that queryset. Is this really the way to go? I'm sure there is something simpler?

```
for obj in qs:
  obj.my_attr = True 
  obj.save()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just do the changes in bulk, although this will not fire the Model's `save()` callbacks:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(..).update(my_attr=True)
```

Documentation: [Updating multiple objects at once](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I've completely missed the 'update' method! Thanks.

Comment: +1 - although I think your "may not" can be changed to "will not", right?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I wrote it before I found the documentation. :)